# Looking for game about searching for alien artifact

Tags: identify-this-game, pc

I think I was playing the game on pc in the mid 90ties.

I believe the story was, that an alien artifact was crashed on a remote tropical island, and was about to cause an end to the world.
Having been briefed in a real life cut-scene, by an army officer, you were sent as the only one to the island in an experimental tank, which had a weapon and an arm for interacting with stuff.

You then moved around the island in first person view, by going forward or turning left and right.

At some point an alien came jumping out at you, and if you weren't able to kill it, you would fail the mission, resulting in another cut-scene of the officer telling you the world was now going to end, and he would spend his remaining time with his family.

Comment: Can you remember if it was in DOS or Windows? [MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/game/from:1990/genre:tank/platform:dos/platform:win3x/platform:windows/until:1999/sort:moby_score/page:1/) has a list of games by "tank" category that you could search.

Comment: Are you certain you're not combining multiple games perhaps? The military briefing and failure reminds me of Night Trap, but combat is more like Corpse Killer. The Journeyman Project and Timescape have the exploration.